# displayName and photoUrl is null in firebase authentication (android)

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I am using email and password authentication of firebase and saving the name, email photourl etc. But It is showing null in photo url and displaName field. It is showing the email and the uid.

```
firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).addOnCompleteListener{
                    if(it.isSuccessful){
                        val firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.currentUser
                        if (firebaseUser != null) {
                            updateUI(firebaseUser)
                        }
                    } else {
                        if(it.exception is FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException)
                            Toast.makeText(this, "User already registered with this email!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }


    private fun updateUI(firebaseUser: FirebaseUser) {

        val user = User(firebaseUser.uid, firebaseUser.displayName.toString(), firebaseUser.email.toString(), firebaseUser.photoUrl.toString())
        val userDao = UserDao()
        userDao.addUser(user)

        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    }
```

Comment: Probably a newly created user doesn't have a photo and display name set on it yet. See [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser#getdisplayname): "This field will be automatically populated on account creation if the AuthCredential used on FirebaseAuth#signInWithCredential(AuthCredential) contained such information."

Comment: Since you're using Kotlin, aside from my answer, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-email-and-password-in-jetpack-compose-bd70ca56ea91) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithEmailAndPassword).

Answer (score 2):

When a user authenticates in Firebase with email and password successfully, a new [FirebaseUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser) object is created. This means that a new account in Firebase Authentication is created. As you can see in the docs, such an object contains multiple fields, however, not all fields will contain a value. In case of authentication with email and pass, only two fields will be populated, the UID and email. The `displayName` and `photoUrl` fields will remain uninitialized, hence the NullPointerException.

If you want to avoid such cases, then besides the email and password EditTexts, you should also consider adding an additional one for the name for example and then update the FirebaseUser object accordingly.

If you want, for example, to implement [Firebase sign-in with Google](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d), the FirebaseUser object will already have the `displayName` and `photoUrl` fields already populated with data from the Google account.

Comment: Hey Divyansh. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?